# Search bar doesn't work on pressing `Enter` keypad in Community

Tags: community, customer-community, lightning-community, global-search, template

I have a community with template `Customer Account Portal`. It has a global search bar which is built on `Search` template page.

Community page looks like this
[image]

Now When I enter `searchstring` in `search` text bar and click on `magnifying glass` symbol then it displays the results based on `searchstring`.

But when I click on `Enter` keypad on my computer, nothing happens.

Is there a way to fix this.

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers, to all users?

Comment: Yes, @JaredT, It is happening to all users and in Chrome and IE.